# Keep it grammatically correct or user friendly

Tags: website-design

I have a question about what domain I should use as the main domain. 
The domain consists of an abbreviation and a noun. For it to be grammatically correct it should be written with a s in between the abb. and the noun in that language. Right now we are using a different domain and from the analytcis everyone that have been googeling our site has come from googleing the abbreviation the noun but leaving out the s. I am planning on buying both domains but I was wondering what would be the best user experience to use as the main domain and just forward the others.

To keep it anonymous lets say the abbreviation is AAA and the down is class.

Should the main domain be:

AAAsclass.com
or
AAAclass.com

What are the pros and cons?

Comment: This is really a decision for your marketing department.

Comment: This is more of a 'domains are effing cheap, get both' question.

Comment: To be gramamtically correct, should it not be "AAA's class". In other words, you cannot be grammatically correct since you cannot use spaces and apostrophees in a URL anyway. I also see the extra s as something that adds confusion, making the URL less readable. That's a con.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys I will be buying them both but I was wondering witch to use as the main domain.

Comment: @BartGijssens This is not in the English language so there is no apostrophe it would be AAAs class. So you are right about the space though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would be fine with the AAAclass.com because of the fact that if someone were to google "AAA's class" I would assume that AAAclass.com would still appear as the top option. Also if you use the AAAsclass, users may be confused on what a "sclass" is just because it looks like the "s" goes with "class"

If you want to check out some more info on choosing a domain name, check [this link](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-choose-the-right-domain-name) out.